# Generic methods and optional arguments

Tags: c#, optional-arguments, generic-method

Is it possible to write similar construction?
I want to set, somehow, default value for argument of type T.

```
    private T GetNumericVal<T>(string sColName, T defVal = 0)
    {
        string sVal = GetStrVal(sColName);
        T nRes;
        if (!T.TryParse(sVal, out nRes))
            return defVal;

        return nRes;
    }
```

Additionally, I found following link:
[Generic type conversion FROM string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625/generic-type-conversion-from-string)
I think, this code must work

```
private T GetNumericVal<T>(string sColName, T defVal = default(T)) where T : IConvertible
{
    string sVal = GetStrVal(sColName);
    try
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(sVal, typeof(T));
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        return defVal;
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I haven't tried this but change `T defVal = 0` to `T defVal = default(T)`

Answer (score 5):

If you know that T will have a parameterless constructor you can use new T() as such:

```
private T GetNumericVal<T>(string sColName, T defVal = new T()) where T : new()
```

Otherwise you can use default(T)

```
private T GetNumericVal<T>(string sColName, T defVal = default(T))
```

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question that would work to set the default value

```
private T GetNumericVal<T>(string sColName, T defVal = default(T)) 
{
    string sVal = GetStrVal(sColName);
    T nRes;
    if (!T.TryParse(sVal, out nRes))
        return defVal;

    return nRes;
}
```

But you cannot call the static TryParse method since the compiler has no way to know type T declares this static method.

Comment: Yes, I cant call TryParse. But maybe something similar? Maybe add some constraint to type parameter (I mean 'where: ...')? If numeric types implement some converting interface.

Comment: the CLR has no concept of "virtual static methods", the compiler cannot infer static methods from a type. As far as I know there is no clean solution for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196661/calling-a-static-method-on-a-generic-type-parameter for more details