# Parsing strings in custom formats using TypeConverter.ConvertFromString()

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime, type-conversion

Using `TypeConverter.ConvertFromString()`, I need to supply a custom format when parsing data from a string (for example, with `DateTime`: `"ddMMyyyy"` or `"MMMM dd, yyyy"`).

`TypeConverter.ConvertFromString()` has the following overload:

```
public object ConvertFromString(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
                                CultureInfo culture, 
                                string text);
```

I checked up on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedescriptorcontext%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) about `ITypeDescriptorContext`.

> The ITypeDescriptorContext interface provides contextual information
>   about a component. ITypeDescriptorContext is typically used at design
>   time to provide information about a design-time container. This
>   interface is commonly used in type conversion.

This sounds like what I need to use but I cannot find any examples anywhere.

I am using the following generic method:

```
public T ParseValue<T>(string value)
{
    return (T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromString(value);
}
```

Example calling code:

```
DateTime date = ParseValue<DateTime>("02062001");
decimal amount = ParseValue<decimal>("1.3423");
```

I want to be able to parse some kind of generic formatting info into this `ParseValue()` method which can be used by `ConvertFromString()`.

Comment: @Bob- Because sometimes I will be parsing from a string to other data types (not just `DateTime`).  I need to use `TypeDescriptor` so that I can get the appropriate parsing mechanism at runtime.

Comment: I'm confused, you want to convert a DateTime, being represented as a string, to other data types? So like to an int?

Comment: @Bob- I have edited my post with more code examples.  Thanks

Comment: Ah, I see, you're looking for a generic string converter that changes it to the appropriate data type, should really change your title to reflect that. :)

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1833128/1466627) might be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom CultureInfo , holding your format.

Another solution would be to Wrap conversion in some helper method that would use DateTime.Parse for dates and TypeConverter for other types.

Comment: I have considered that (I would also need to specify number formats when parsing decimals, negatives, etc), but it seems like an overkill to have to create a dummy CultureInfo object and just overwrite some relevant property.  And then what is `ITypeDescriptorContext` actually for? Thanks for the reply :)