# Can not convert type int to T

Tags: c#

I run into a compiler error that I am not sure how to resolve it.

Basically, I have a few enum classes described below.

I created abstract classes myTool and myTools deriving from myTool.
The compiler for some reason does not like the way I structured the constructor for MyTools and threw error

> CS0030: Can not convert type int to type T.

Please advice me how to resolve this.

```
public enum TOOLS
{
  HAMMER =1,
  DRILL = 2,
  SCREWDRIVER =3,
  VACUUM=4
}

public enum EQUIPMENTS
{
  MOWER=1,
  TRIMMER=2,
  SNOWBLOWER=3
}

public abstract class MyTool
{
  protected T _myStuff
  int quantity
  double price
  public MyTool(T t)
  {
  _myStuff =t;
  }
  ... properties...
}

public abstract class MyTools<T>:myTool<T>
where T:System.Enum
{
  protected MyTool<T>[] _myTools;
  public MyTool<T> this[int i]=> this._myTools[i];
  public MyTools(int count, T t):base(t)
  {
    _myTools = new MyTools<T>[count];
    for (int i=0; i<count;i++)
    {
      _myTools[i]=(T)(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `public abstract class MyTools<T>:myTool<T>` that's a really, really, really terrible idea to have both a `MyTools<T>` type and a `myTools<T>` type. Really terrible idea...

Comment: `_myTools[i]` is a `MyTool<T>` object, how can you assign a `T`? Do you have an implicit operator? -- This composition seems quite convoluted

Comment: @Jimi: That is the problem and Olivier has pointed out... I am new to generic class and made mistakes

Comment: @user1205746 I'd strongly recommend sticking with default language naming guidelines for *public examples*. Naming a type with lowercase or all upper case is unusual and potentially confusing. Please re-read the [mre] guidance - there is zero requirements for code in SO question to match your private version as long as it demonstrates the problem. Note that [codereview.se] guidance is obviously opposite as they review the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert an `int` into a generic type constrained as `System.Enum` like this:

```cs
T enumValue = (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), intValue);
```

or simply

```cs
T enumValue = (T)(object)intValue;
```

Comment: I appreciate you hint. However, when I changed my assignment to _myTools[i] = (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), (i+1)) or your other suggestion, I got can not implicit convert type T to MyTools<T>

Comment: But you will get a recursion if you do this in the constructor. Probably the declaration should be `protected T[] _myTools;` and then my solution will work.

Comment: Thanks again. You are right, when I changed to (MyTool<T>)Enum.ToObject(typeof(MyTool<T>),(i+1)); it seems to work!.. I can not new since this is an abstract class

Comment: The question is what do you want to add to `_myTools`? If you add another `MyTools<T>`, this will call the constructor recursively, because creating this object call the constructor again creating yet another `MyTools<T>`, and so on... Maybe you should make `MyTool<T>` not abstract and add `MyTool<T>` objects to the array.

Comment: Your object model allows you to create tools containing tools containing tools... It that that intentional?

Comment: My intention was to be able to generate different classes of tools (defined by the enum).. In MyTools, I can have different instances of MyTool... does it make sense? Then another class like myFactory will be a concrete class inheriting MyTools.. Maybe my design is not good

Comment: Having a class hierarchy of tools basically makes the enums superfluous. You would have a hierarchy like `Tool` > `Equipment` > `Trimmer` (all non-generic). You can then test `tool is Trimmer` instead of `tool.myStuff = EQUIPMENT.TRIMMER` or something like this. Maybe `MyTools` should not derive from `MyTool` and be called `ToolCollection<T>` instead `where T : Tool`.

Comment: Ah.. using collection is the better alternative.. Thanks again, Olivier

Comment: Note that `(T)(object)intValue` conversion blows up at run-time if enum is not int-based (like `enum X : long {Foo, Bar};`), so avoiding whole "increment enum value" problem is better option if possible, otherwise   `Enum.ToObject` is the way to go.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yeah, It did! I originally had that and it blew up at run time..

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic type converter

```
public static class TConverter
{
 public static T ChangeType<T>(object value)
 {
     return (T)ChangeType(typeof(T), value);
 }

 public static object ChangeType(Type t, object value)
 {
    TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(t);
    return tc.ConvertFrom(value);
 }

 public static void RegisterTypeConverter<T, TC>() where TC : TypeConverter
 {

    TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(T), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(TC)));
 }
}
```

and usage:

```
 TConverter.ChangeType<T>(intValue);
```

it is from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1833128/2286743